# Android XML Composite View

Tags: android

I'm new to Android development, and am having a tough time working something out. I want to make a composite view (called SkillDiceGroup) of a TextView, EditText, and SkillDiceButton (which is an extension of the Button class). I have it working when declaring my SkillDiceGroup as pure code, and putting this in my XML layout:

```
   <com.jeremybush.d20.SkillDiceGroup android:id="@+id/skillDiceTest"
     android:title="Foobar!"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   </com.jeremybush.d20.SkillDiceGroup>
```

And I have this code:

```
public class SkillDiceGroup extends LinearLayout
{
 // The View components
 private TextView mTitle;
 private EditText mSkill;
 private SkillDiceButton mDice;

 public SkillDiceGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
 {
  super(context);

  this.setOrientation(HORIZONTAL);

  mTitle = new TextView(context);
        mTitle.setText("foobar");
  addView(mTitle, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
  ));

  mSkill = new EditText(context);
  addView(mSkill, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
  ));

  mDice = new SkillDiceButton(context, attrs);
  mDice.setText("d20");
  addView(mDice, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
  ));
 }

 private class SkillDiceButton extends DiceButton
 {
  public SkillDiceButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
   super(context, attrs);
  }

  public void onClick(View view)
  {
   modifier = Integer.parseInt(mSkill.getText().toString());

   super.onClick(view);
  }
 }
}
```

This works how I want it, but I would like to declare the three items in the xml view on their own. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the extensive documention Android provides regarding xml layouts, for example: [declaring layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html), [common layout objects](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html), and [hello views](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html) which has an detailed example of each layout type.

Taken directly from the LinearLayout tutorial, a layout with 3 items:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:text="row one"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="row two"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="row three"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="row four"
        android:textSize="15pt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Just replace the second two text views with an EditText and a SkillDiceButton.

Comment: I have been reading documentation, but I'm not sure this example is quite the same. Notice at the end of my code, i have the modifier assignment where I reference mSkill variable. Because of the logic I need, I don't think your example is a direct translation. I could be (and probably am) wrong though.

Comment: Any logic should be in your Activity class, not your view class.  You can access the elements of your layout by id if you want to view text from them or add click listeners.  It might help you to work through one of the complete examples, like the notepad tutorial: http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/notepad/index.html, to see how everything is supposed to fit together.

Comment: This is the correct way to go, if your custom views need their own extra attributes you can add your own xmlns as well.  The panel widget in this project has an example of how to add your own attributes.  http://code.google.com/p/android-misc-widgets/    you can also use findViewById to get a reference to your custom views in your Activity and manually set extra attributes.  Neither solution would be wrong.

Comment: What I'm ultimately trying to do is when you click a DiceButton view, it reads in an associated TextView object. I was told that using a composite view is how this should be done. Following DRY, I made my own DiceButton class, and overrode the onClick action of it, which will show an alert of a dice roll. I did it this way so that I would not have to manually declare 15-20 click handlers for the buttons.

Comment: Are your 15-20 buttons on the same page?  In a list?  Each in its own Activity?  That is very different from your original question, you might want to go back and better explain what exactly you are trying to accomplish so we can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, they are all on the same screen. I was unaware that was an issue. I asked how I can turn the code I wrote into a single XML structure. The end goal of what I'm trying to do is have a DiceButton that when clicked, generates a random number and adds the value from a related EditText field, then shows that in an alert box. I was advised to create a composite view class to accomplish this, so that the text field and the button were "glued together". As you can see, the code indeed does do this, but I was hoping to streamline it by using XML for the "subview" objects.

Comment: You might want to look at using a ListView.  This allows you to supply an XML layout, like the one described above, and add the business logic for the button and EditText once in the getView method of the adapter.  The logic will be applied to every item in the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to create your own view/widget that 'hides' internal layout structure, and can be reusable in various places - you should read document about  [creating custom components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)

also read about  tag, and [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)

But if want to use SkillDiceGroup only once - just create layout as proposed by Mayra

Comment: Right, like I said in the other comment, I will be reusing this thing 15-20 times.